# Where does 'Motion' web cam interface store image files?

Tags: motion

I've tested a USB webcam with motion with the motion detection on. I suspect that's why the memory card has no space left. I cannot in the name find the directory where Motion stores the images saved from the camera. Any idea where could I find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default target directory should be your actual working directory.
E.g. if you startet motion in your terminal from `/home/pi`, the saved images should be located there.

If your want to change this directory i would recommend reading this article and configure the `motion.conf` file:
http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/AdvancedFilenames

Maybe in your case this directory is already set.

Answer (score 7):

The default directory is   **/var/lib/motion**
which is set in the **/etc/motion/motion.conf** file
using the **target_dir** variable