# What folder does Motioneyeos save movie files to on my microSD card?

Tags: camera, pi-zero

I am using a RaspberryPi Zero W to build a nest camera for wildlife studies. The hope is to have a camera run continuously while attached to a battery and solar system while saving files to the onboard microSD card. I have successfully booted MotioneyeOS and everything seems to run fine aside from not being able to find any video files when I plug the SD card into my laptop afterward.

The other oddity I have noticed is that when I write the MotioneyeOS to the SD card, it creates two other partitioned drives (F/G) that are shown us corrupted and in need of formatting.

Keep in mind, my skills are limited here, I'm a biologist by training just trying to fake it here.

**Can anyone tell me what the file pathway is to the microSD card?**

eg what pathway should i type in the interface to send files to the SD card?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where does 'Motion' web cam interface store image files?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/39502/where-does-motion-web-cam-interface-store-image-files)

Answer (score 0):

Look in `/etc/motion/motion.conf` for `target_dir`